# jQuery UI dropover not always fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a page with two DIVs, both of which are droppable. One of them (#droppable2) is initially hidden and is only shown when I hover the draggable item over the first DIV #droppable (with the dropover event). Example see here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AdLJr

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="droppable">Drop here 1</div>
<div id="droppable2" style="top: 300px; display: none;">Drop here 2</div>
<div id="draggable">Drag me</div>
<div id="log"></div>
```

JS:

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
$( "#droppable,#droppable2" ).droppable({
drop: function() {
    $('#log').html($('#log').html() + '<br>DROP');
},
over: function() {
    $('#log').html($('#log').html() + '<br>over');
    $('#droppable2').show();
}
});
```

However, when I now hover the draggable item over the second DIV, its dropover event is not fired like it should. Only when drop the draggable item and then pick it up again does it seem to work. The drop event already works on the first try though.

Any ideas what's causing this? I assume this might be a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is an actual answer. Change your first JS line to this:

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({ refreshPositions: true });
```

From the jQuery UI `draggable` docs for the `refreshPositions` option:

```
If set to true, all droppable positions are calculated on every mousemove.
Caution: This solves issues on highly dynamic pages,
    but dramatically decreases performance.
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I actually didn't enable the options directly because of the performance warning, but thanks to your post I did find a solution for triggering a single position refresh on-demand: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-make-draggable-execute-refreshpositions-not-on-every-mousemove-but-with-a-specific-callback -- I have have posted a fixed, working example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gjwkx

Answer (score 0):

I also did it in that way with this line $( "#draggable" ).draggable({ refreshPositions: true });, but using a class draggable, but only works for once. I can only drag and drop for once one element. And if there is another element in the place where a droped they all don't work

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32470437)